# bash script selecting the last path variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I am writing my first bash script. I am making it install all the repos I have on GitHub.

```
warpInLocations=("git@github.com:acc/toolkit.git" "git@github.com:acc/sms.git" "git@github.com:acc/boogle.git" "git@github.com:acc/cairo.git")
```

Those are them when I install them.

```
echo "warping in toolkit, sms, boogle and cairo"
for repo in "${warpInLocations[@]}"
do
  warpInDir=$(echo ${warpToLocation}${repo} | cut -d'.' -f1)
  if [ -d "$warpToLocation"]; then
    echo "somethings in the way.. $warpInDir all ready exists"
  else
    git clone $repo $warpInDir
  fi

done
```

This line here, I wanted it to give me a folder named `toolkit` or `sms`, so after the `/` and before the `.` in the warp in locations, but it's selecting `git@github` instead. I guess, because it's after the `.`.

How can I get it to select the name in the repo?

Comment: That's a bit confusing. What do you want? The string between the last `/` and the following `.`?

Comment: each instance of the the warpInLocations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dir=$(basename git@github.com:acc/toolkit.git .git)
```

will set `$dir` to `toolkit`.

also useful is the `dirname` command.

Answer (score 7):

You need to proceed in two steps:

```
dir=git@github.com:acc/toolkit.git
dir=${dir#*/}                       # Remove everything up to /
dir=${dir%.*}                       # Remove everything from the .
```

Answer (score 2):

in bash, you can also use a 
regular expression and capturing parentheses

```
for repo in "${warpInLocations[@]}"; do
    [[ $repo =~ /([^.]+)\. ]] && dir=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    warpInDir=${warpToLocation}$dir
    # ...
```